# Subdomain api.domain.com - more vunerable to attacks?

Tags: api, domain

I am in the process of setting up an api which will have the subdomain "api.", I have been advised to change this to something "less obvious" to avoid automated attacks against it.
I can't find any advice on naming subdomains to avoid attacks and from a business perspective the benefit of this approach is alerting non-tech professionals that we have an api.

Is this legitimate advice which I should seriously consider or is this something that will yield little to nothing in the way of security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that will yield little to nothing in the way of security.

The subdomain will still be leaked:

- In your client that uses the API. To connect to the API the client has to have the correct URL, and someone with the client can extract this URL.
- In plaintext traffic when using SNI (Server Name Indication). The subdomain is sent plain text before setting up an encrypted connection, in most cases.
- In certificate transparency logs. If you request a HTTPS certificate for your domain, the domainname will end up in a [public log](https://crt.sh/?q=secretapi.%.%).

Comment: Thanks, I felt it wouldn't improve security much but it's always nice to double check. I appreciate your help